# Highcharts custom buttons with tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, tooltip

actually I work with highcharts and I would like to ask if I can add some tooltip to the custom buttons of highcharts.
Therefore I added to my chart the following code:

```
            exporting: {
            buttons: {
                customButton: {
                    x: -62,
                    onclick: function () {
                        $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
                    },
                    symbol: 'circle'
                }
            }
        },
```

But unfortunately the onclick function doesn't trigger a tooltip.
I would be very happy, if you can help me.

Thank you in advance.

Greets

Comment: Could you create simple demo with that code? Like in jsFiddle? I don't know which library you are using to get tooltip..

Answer (score 1):

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("selector").attr("alt","tooltipvalue");
});
```

Comment: Your answer appears in the *very* low quality review queue. Can you please elaborate on why this answers the question and also where you would insert this code snippet.